# can we pass post parameter in route in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to pass static value in route in laravel, is it possible in laravel ? here is what i have in route,

```
Route::post('manage-package', 'Api\App\HomeController@store');
```

I want to pass static value in this route, like `params_one = 1`, can we pass such parameter in route ? it will be great if anyone have something idea like this

Comment: `Route::post('manage-package/{value}'` for post static parameter

Comment: If it is a static value, it is a good idea to place it as a route parameter in the route definition.

Answer (score 2):

One way to pass arbitrary data is to treat it like a route parameter by setting a default parameter on the route. This will cause that data to be passed to the route action as an argument just like if it was a route parameter:

```
Route::post('manage-package', 'Api\App\HomeController@store')
    ->defaults('params_one', 1);

public function store($params_one)
```

You could also use the 'actions' array of the Route but then would have to pull it from the route as opposed to having it passed like a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by defining an **Optional Parameters** in your route

```
Route::post('manage-package/{params_one?}', 'Api\App\HomeController@store');
```

And in the controller you define a default value of that parameter as the controller function receive each URL parameter as argument

```
public function store($params_one = 1){}
```

You can learn more about [Optional Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters)